# Use DFT (`fft()`) to Replicate 2D Convolution (`conv()`)

Tags: image-processing, fft, matlab, convolution, julia

In MATLAB, I tried to convert the `fft2`-based multiplication using `conv2`.

```matlab
Z = rand(100);
k = rand(100);
Fk= fft2(k);
V1 = real(ifft2(Fk.*ifftshift(Z)));
V2 = conv2(ifft2(ifftshift(Z)),k, 'same');
```

I want `V1` and `V2` to be the same, but they're not.
I need to avoid using the FFT while calculating `V2`.

Comment: Please don’t cross-post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77508781/7328782

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cross posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77508781/convert-fft2-version-to-conv2-matlab

Comment: this is not surprising – `real(IFFT(a .* b))` simply isn't the same as `conv(a, b)`. The first one discards the imaginary part, the second doesn't. The first one does a cyclic convolution, the second doesn't. They are simply not the same operation. AND, big surprise, the implementation of `conv2` *almost surely* internally uses an FFT (though of a different size than you are), because convolution is usually implemented using appropriate padding and FFTs. Which brings one to the next question: why would you want to avoid the FFT?

Comment: @MarcusMüller something interesting/weird about MATLAB is that the ```conv``` function doesn't use FFT, it actually does "flip-and-shift" the signals. Using ```conv``` with anything more than a few hundred samples becomes very slow, and so one can use the ```xcorr``` function, where FFTs are used, as a proxy for convolution

Comment: @Engineer, It is a great decision by MATLAB developers to make `conv()` based on the spatial operation and not in the frequency domain. See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52760. In many cases the spatial implementation is faster. I prefer the functions to be explicit and not implicit.

Comment: @Royi yup, it is documented in a Mathworks blog here: https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/11/03/the-conv-function-and-implementation-tradeoffs/. Depends on how many samples you use! Seems to align with your previous answer too

Comment: @Engineer, This is a very old `conv()`. They have improved it greatly since then. So the line higher. Nothin new in this, there is asymptotic complexity and the constant.

Comment: @Royi ok...sounds like we agree

Answer (score 2):

HINT

```
%% 1D example
Nx = 200; % number of samples in x
Ny = 100; % number of samples in y

x = randn(Nx, 1); % random data x
y = randn(Ny, 1); % random data y

xp = padarray(x, Ny-1, 0, "post"); % pad x with 0's
yp = padarray(y, Nx-1, 0, "post"); % pad y with 0's

z_conv = conv(x, y); % direct method
z_fft = ifft(fft(xp) .* fft(yp)); % FFT based method
```

Comment: This will result in `full` convolution. The OP is after `same`.

Comment: I answered as a "hint" because this smelt like a homework problem

Answer (score 1):

You have a MATLAB Code as an answer in [Replicate MATLAB's `conv2()` in Frequency Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74803).

For discrete signals, the multiplication in frequency domain is equivalent of *circulant convolution*. In order to achieve linear convolution with different shapes (`full`, `same`, `valid`) you need to do some padding and indices arithmetic as shown in the linked answer.

#### Julia Implementation

As a practice, let's implement this in Julia.

```
using FFTW;

function Conv2DFreqDom( mI :: Matrix{T}, mH :: Matrix{T}; convMode :: ConvMode = CONV_MODE_FULL ) where {T <: AbstractFloat}

    numRowsI, numColsI = size(mI);
    numRowsH, numColsH = size(mH);

    if (convMode == CONV_MODE_FULL)
        numRowsFft  = numRowsI + numRowsH - 1;
        numColsFft  = numColsI + numColsH - 1;
        mO = Matrix{T}(undef, (numRowsI, numColsI) .+ (numRowsH, numColsH) .- 1);
    elseif (convMode == CONV_MODE_SAME)
        numRowsFft  = numRowsI + numRowsH;
        numColsFft  = numColsI + numColsH;
        mO = Matrix{T}(undef, (numRowsI, numColsI));
    elseif (convMode == CONV_MODE_VALID)
        numRowsFft  = numRowsI;
        numColsFft  = numColsI;
        mO = Matrix{T}(undef, (numRowsI, numColsI) .- (numRowsH, numColsH) .+ 1);
    end

    mT1 = Matrix{complex(T)}(undef, numRowsFft, numColsFft);
    mT2 = Matrix{complex(T)}(undef, numRowsFft, numColsFft);

    Conv2DFreqDom!(mO, mI, mH, mT1, mT2; convMode = convMode);

    return mO;

end

function Conv2DFreqDom!( mO :: Matrix{T}, mI :: Matrix{T}, mH :: Matrix{T}, mT1 :: Matrix{Complex{T}}, mT2 :: Matrix{Complex{T}}; convMode :: ConvMode = CONV_MODE_FULL ) where {T <: AbstractFloat}

    numRowsI, numColsI = size(mI);
    numRowsH, numColsH = size(mH);

    if (convMode == CONV_MODE_FULL)
        numRowsFft  = numRowsI + numRowsH - 1;
        numColsFft  = numColsI + numColsH - 1;
        firstRowIdx = 1;
        firstColIdx = 1;
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
    elseif (convMode == CONV_MODE_SAME)
        numRowsFft  = numRowsI + numRowsH;
        numColsFft  = numColsI + numColsH;
        firstRowIdx = ceil((numRowsH + 1) / 2);
        firstColIdx = ceil((numColsH + 1) / 2);
        lastRowIdx  = firstRowIdx + numRowsI - 1;
        lastColdIdx = firstColIdx + numColsI - 1;
    elseif (convMode == CONV_MODE_VALID)
        numRowsFft  = numRowsI;
        numColsFft  = numColsI;
        firstRowIdx = numRowsH;
        firstColIdx = numColsH;
        lastRowIdx  = numRowsFft;
        lastColdIdx = numColsFft;
    end

    mT1[1:numRowsI, 1:numColsI] .= mI;
    mT2[1:numRowsH, 1:numColsH] .= mH;
    fft!(mT1);
    fft!(mT2);

    mT1 .*= mT2;
    ifft!(mT1);

    mO .= real.(@view mT1[firstRowIdx:lastRowIdx, firstRowIdx:lastRowIdx]);

end

# Padding
mIPad = PadArray(mI, (kernelRadius, kernelRadius); padMode = padMode);

# Generating the Reference
mORef = Conv2D(mIPad, mH; convMode =  convMode);

# Using FFT
mODft = Conv2DFreqDom(mIPad, mH; convMode =  convMode);
```

This will yield a perfect result as:

```
julia> maximum(abs.(mORef - mODft))
1.1102230246251565e-15
```

The full Julia code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q90036 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q90036` folder).

Comment: Any feedback form the one who `-1`?